# Correct Positioning of content in html with bootstrap after adding .json data

Tags: html, css, json, twitter-bootstrap

so after the text containing the emergency hotlines were aligned properly, I just cant seen to place the text under the image in order to present the data three in a row (I tried col-4 but json messed it up). My goal is image, then content of the numbers directly below it. I tried: text-align, float, display, media. any help would be appreciated thank you.

heres the current situation:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niCx2.png)

UPDATE: here is the JSfiddle of the question, placeholders are used to show the positioning. https://jsfiddle.net/ktbmLaq8/

```
<div class="module-text" ng-controller="VolunteerAidCtrl">
    <p class="services-margin">In an emergency, please contact the appropriate service in their respective ASEAN countries for the proper response. These numbers can be called either on landline and mobile and consist of the Police Department, Fire Department, and the Hospital Ambulance. </p>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." ng-model="search">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
          </span>
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="service in services | filter:search">
          <div class="media">
            <div class="media-left">
                <img class="flagsize" ng-src="{{service.flagimgurl}}">
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading country-title" ng-bind="service.country"></h4>
              <table class="table">
                <tr class="remove-border">
                  <td ng-bind="service.hl1"></td>
                  <td class="text-left">
                    <div ng-bind="service.hl1num1"></div>
                    <div ng-bind="service.hl1num2"></div>
                    <div ng-bind="service.hl1num3"></div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="remove-border">
                  <td ng-bind="service.hl2"></td>
                  <td class="text-left">
                    <div ng-bind="service.hl2num1"></div>
                    <div ng-bind="service.hl2num2"></div>
                    <div ng-bind="service.hl2num3"></div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="remove-border">
                  <td ng-bind="service.hl3"></td>
                  <td class="text-left">
                    <div ng-bind="service.hl3num1"></div>
                    <div ng-bind="service.hl3num2"></div>
                    <div ng-bind="service.hl3num3"></div>
                  </td>         
                </tr>
                <tr class="remove-border">
                  <td ng-bind="service.hl4"></td>
                  <td class="text-left">
                    <div ng-bind="service.hl4num1"></div>
                    <div ng-bind="service.hl4num2"></div>
                    <div ng-bind="service.hl4num3"></div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
        <!-- <div class="col-md-3 services-margin">
            <img class="flagsize" src="../../../img/flag_cambodia.png">
                <table class="services">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="country-title">Cambodia</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fire</td>
                        <td>:114</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>:023 723 555</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Police</td>
                        <td>:117</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>:023 366 841</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>:023 720 235</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ambulance&nbsp&nbsp</td>
                        <td>:119</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>:023 724 891</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 services-margin">
            <img class="flagsize" src="../../../img/flag_indonesia.png">
                <table class="services">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="country-title">Indonesia</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Police</td>
                        <td>:110</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>:112</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fire</td>
                        <td>:113</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ambulance and Rescue&nbsp&nbsp</td>
                        <td>:118</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Medical Emergencies</td>
                        <td>:119</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 services-margin">
            <img class="flagsize" src="../../../img/flag_laos.png">
                <table class="services">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="country-title">Laos</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fire</td>
                        <td>:190</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Police</td>
                        <td>:191</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ambulance&nbsp&nbsp</td>
                        <td>:195</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 services-margin">
            <img class="flagsize" src="../../../img/flag_malaysia.png">
                <table class="services">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="country-title">Malaysia</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fire and Rescue</td>
                        <td>:994</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>:114</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ambulance/Police&nbsp&nbsp</td>
                        <td>:999</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>:112</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 services-margin">
            <img class="flagsize" src="../../../img/flag_myanmar.png">
                <table class="services">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="country-title">Myanmar</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fire</td>
                        <td>:191</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ambulance&nbsp&nbsp</td>
                        <td>:192</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Police</td>
                        <td>:199</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 services-margin">
            <img class="flagsize" src="../../../img/flag_philippines.png">
                <table class="services">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="country-title">Philippines</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Disaster Risk&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</td>
                        <td>:(02) 911-1406</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>:(02) 912-1406</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Police</td>
                        <td>:117</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>:911</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fire</td>
                        <td>:117</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>:(02) 729-5166</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>:(02) 410-6319</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Red Cross</td>
                        <td>:(02) 527-0000</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>:(02) 527-8385</td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 services-margin">
            <img class="flagsize" src="../../../img/flag_singapore.png">
                <table class="services">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="country-title">Singapore</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fire and Ambulance&nbsp&nbsp</td>
                        <td>:995</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Police</td>
                        <td>:999</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 services-margin">
            <img class="flagsize" src="../../../img/flag_thailand.png">
                <table class="services">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="country-title">Thailand</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Police</td>
                        <td>:191</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>:1195</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fire</td>
                        <td>:199</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ambulance and Rescue&nbsp&nbsp</td>
                        <td>:1554</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>:1669</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 services-margin">
            <img class="flagsize" src="../../../img/flag_vietnam.png">
                <table class="services">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="country-title">Vietnam</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Police</td>
                        <td>:113</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fire</td>
                        <td>:114</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ambulance&nbsp&nbsp</td>
                        <td>:115</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </div> -->
```

Comment: Hi there. Unfortunately you use images in your HTML code that are only available locally. These images aren't available for us, so we can't use them for reference. Can you please update your code so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks!

Comment: i apologize ill update it shortly

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ktbmLaq8/ here' a JSFiddle

Comment: The problem is that in your HTML structure, you are listing the information for *all* countries in a single collective table, while displaying the flags for each country outside of the table. You should code flag 1, then info 1, then flag 2, info 2, etc. Convert all of your table elements to `<div>`, and add classes to each of the new divs so you can target them more easily. Then it's just a combination of `float: left` and `clear: both` :) -- I'm working on a fiddle for this, please bear with me :)

Comment: thank you appreciate it completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your HTML structure, you are listing the information for all countries in a single collective table, while displaying the flags for each country outside of the table. It's not very easy to 'break up' this information that's all stored in the table.

The best way to solve this is to handle both the flag and service information for each country at the *same time*. In order to do this, first we convert all of your table elements to `<div>s`, add classes to each of the new divs, and slightly change their order:

```
<div class="country">
    <div class="media-left">
      <a href="#">
        <img class="media-object flagsize" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/67/Flag_of_Brunei_1906-1959.svg/1000px-Flag_of_Brunei_1906-1959.svg.png" alt="...">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="country-info">
      <h4 class="media-heading country-title" ng-bind="service.country">Brunei</h4>
      <div class="left" ng-bind="service.hl1">Service 1</div>
      <div class="right" ng-bind="service.hl1num1">111</div>
      <div class="left" ng-bind="service.hl2">Service 2</div>
      <div class="right" ng-bind="service.hl1num2">222</div>
      <div class="left" ng-bind="service.hl3">Service 2</div>
      <div class="right" ng-bind="service.hl1num3">333</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can target the respective contents **much** more easily :)

```
img.flagsize, .country-info {
  max-width: 200px
}

.left {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}
```

You'll also need to specify that `.country-info` should be the same width as `img.flagsize`, or else the information will get pushed to the right of the page:

```
img.flagsize, .country-info {
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

I've created a fiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/Lte8d6s1/).

With this structure, you can change just about any aspect of the layout you'd like -- margins, padding, and heights no longer pose an issue ;)

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks that works well on its own. however as soon as I placed it in my html with my json data, the numbers stretch out to the far right. Is there some sort of quick fixes?

Comment: Did you copy the CSS from the snippet I posted above, or the CSS from the JSFiddle? Because in the JSFiddle I also specified that the `.country-info` should be the same size as the flag. I forgot to include that reference in the snippet here. I've updated my answer here to showcase that as well :)

Comment: oh i apologised, overlooked that css file haha, i thought it was the image width. Anyway thanks a lot :D